# XamarinUITest pass arguments to AndroidAppConfigurator

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.uitest

Appcenter introduces some variables which can be accessed while UITesting in AppCenter like described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/environment-variables). For iOS it is possible to pass additional arguments while starting the app

```
            ConfigureApp
                .iOS
                .AutEnvironmentVars(new Dictionary<string, string> {{"MY_ARGUMENT", "1"}})
```

But I cannot really find a method for Android to pass additional arguments and get them later with `InstrumentationRegistry` as described in the docs. So how can I pass arguments while starting the Android app for testing and read them?

Comment: Did you try Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables?

Comment: Yes I tried that. The problem is that the environment variables defined by AppCenter are just accessible in the UITest project and are not passed to the tested app (on Android). This is also described in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/environment-variables#support-by-framework. Therefore I am searching for another approach.